# Find corresponding graph edge to a vertex in line graph using networkx

Tags: networkx

I have a graph G, defined using its weight matrix W using `networkx` package

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(W)
```

I introduce line graph I(G) of the graph G. Using `networkx`, I can find the line graph as

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_numpy_matrix(W)
I = nx.line_graph(G)
```

The `networkx` documentation reads

> Graph, node, and edge data are not propagated to the new graph

My problem is how to find the edge v_iv_j of graph G that corresponds to a particular vertex v'_k in line graph I(G).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation you noted, the references to `attributes` means things like weights/colors that you may have associated with the graph `G`.  So this doesn't have to do with relating the nodes of `l(G)` with edges of `G`.

It's actually very straightforward to answer your question.

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,3), (2,3),(2,4)])
L = nx.line_graph(G)

L.nodes()
> NodeView(((2, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3), (1, 3)))

L.edges()
> EdgeView([((2, 4), (2, 3)), ((2, 4), (1, 2)), ((1, 2), (2, 3)), ((1, 2), (1, 3)), ((2, 3), (1, 3))])

list(L.neighbors((2,4)))
> [(2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

So the edge `(2,4)` in `G` becomes a node `(2,4)` in `L`  That node has neighbors `(2,3)` and `(1,2)`.  In other words, if `Lnode` is a node in `L` it will be a tuple of two values, `Lnode = (v_i, v_j)` where the edge in the original graph `G` was from `v_i` to `v_j`.